# How to convert JavaScript to CoffeeScript for two case

Tags: javascript, for-loop, coffeescript, settimeout

I'm using CoffeeScript in a Rails application. How to convert JavaScript to CoffeeScript for two case:

```
var colIndex = 0,
    colRight = 0,
    cols = this.grid.columnX,
    len = cols.length,
    cmatch = false;

for (len; colIndex < len; colIndex++) {
    colRight = cols[colIndex].x + cols[colIndex].w;
    if (xy[0] < colRight) {
        cmatch = true;
    break;
    }
}
```

and

```
setTimeout(function() {
    d.scrollTop = st;
}, 10);
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tool for converting JavaScript to CoffeeScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510906/is-there-a-tool-for-converting-javascript-to-coffeescript)

Answer (score 1):

1.CoffeeScript supports `for in` iteration on an array, so you simply don't need `colIndex` and `len`.

```
colRight = 0
cols = @grid.columnX
cmatch = false

for col in cols
  colRight = col.x + col.w
  if xy[0] < colRight
    cmatch = true
    break
```

2.

```
setTimeout (-> d.scrollTop = st), 10
```

Comment: The setTimeout looks fine, but you'd overlooking that the OP might have actually wanted to have the index of the matching item. See my answer for a solution that provides that.

Answer (score 0):

there is a site to do this work [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/):

the answers are:

1

```
colIndex = 0
colRight = 0
cols = @grid.columnX
len = cols.length
cmatch = false
len
while colIndex < len
  colRight = cols[colIndex].x + cols[colIndex].w
  if xy[0] < colRight
    cmatch = true
    break
  colIndex++
```

2

```
setTimeout (->
  d.scrollTop = st
), 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my stab at it:

```
for col, idx in @grid.columnX when xy[0] < colRight = (col.x + col.w)
  cmatch = idx
  break
```

So after the loop, cmatch will either be undefined or the index of the match, while colRight will be the matching col's right side, or the last col's right side if no match is found.

Here's a fiddle to play in: http://jsfiddle.net/fNSXE/1/